# Garbage disposal reset

Tags: electrical

Testing with non contact voltage detector I get intermitent positve where flexible conduit enters garbage disposal even with breaker off.  Is it a false positve or is th switch bad? Reset triped while in use

Comment: ncvd's aren't 100%, by any means; lots of false positives, a few false negatives

Answer (score 1):

It may be a phantom voltage, that you are seeing, many disposal units have a Allen key you can turn to make sure things are free if it turns + the reset on the disposal motor is set and the breaker is reset if it still won't start check the wiring at the switch. Disposals pull a large starting current and if back stabs were used it may have burned one of the stabs if you pull the switch out and it starts working get a new switch before it burns the wire off.